# move QMessageBox to bottom-right corner of the screen

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyside, pyqt5

I want to move QMessageBox to bottom-right corner of the screen, following is my code,but doesn't work as expected , anyone can explain why? How to fix the problem here ?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def moveToBottomRight(msgBox):

    msgBox.addButton("重计", QMessageBox.ActionRole)
    msgBox.addButton("停计", QMessageBox.ActionRole)
    msgBox.addButton('继续', QMessageBox.ActionRole)

    screenGeometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
    screenGeo = screenGeometry.bottomRight()

    msgGeo = msgBox.frameGeometry()

    msgGeo.moveBottomRight(screenGeo)

    msgBox.move(msgGeo.topLeft())


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    moveToBottomRight(msgBox)
    msgBox.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think before `msgBox` is show its frame (size) of ti is not defined, so you are using invalid value for calculations.

Comment: @MarekR seems you are right , when putting moveToBottomRight(msgBox) after 
   msgBox.show(), it works as I want ,but msgBox  show in  the origin position at first ,then immediately move to the destination position  ,how to let it show at the destination position directly without firstly showing  in the origin position  ?

Comment: @iMath does it work properly if you call `msgBox.ensurePolished();` before you get its frame geometry?

Comment: @MarekR After changing the code like this,worked expectedly codepad.org/KiifTwPB

Comment: @thuga After changing the code like this,worked expectedly codepad.org/KiifTwPB

Answer (score 1):

`msgBox.frameGeometry()` does not get a valid value, that's because the message box is not shown. You should use `sizeHint()` like :

```
msgGeo = QRect(QPoint(0,0), msgBox.sizeHint())
```

`sizeHint` holds the recommended size for the widget. It's default implementation returns the layout's preferred size if the widget has a layout.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion on Win7, the fact is the msgBox is  partially concealed by the task bar, this is not I want .

Comment: Have you tried `screenGeometry()` instead of `availableGeometry()`?

Comment: when changed to screenGeometry(), more area is concealed

Comment: Then you can use something like `screenGeometry = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry().adjusted(0,0,0,-100)` to adjust the bottom of screen geometry. You can change the `100` value to an appropriate one.